# iOS SDK 3.0 - FBFriendPickerViewController with FBCacheDescriptor - limited friends list

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I would like to present a limited list of friends (e.g. generated by a specific FQL) using [FBFriendsPickerViewController](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdk-reference/iossdk/3.0/class/FBFriendPickerViewController/). The documentation hints that the friends list can be pre-fetched using [FBCacheDescriptor](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdk-reference/iossdk/3.0/class/FBCacheDescriptor/), but the documentation of the latter is poor. I didn't find any example in the SDK samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [FBFriendPickerDelegate](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdk-reference/iossdk/3.0/protocol/FBFriendPickerDelegate/#//api/name/friendPickerViewController%3ashouldIncludeUser%3a):

```
- (BOOL)friendPickerViewController:(FBFriendPickerViewController *)friendPicker shouldIncludeUser:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
```

Comment: This seems to be working. I need to keep a list of filtered friends (using the example fql directive) and then compare in every callback. Not elegant, but working. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, FBCacheDescriptor is to prefetch the data you need, to improve the responsiveness of the table views. For example, if you want to cache the friend picker list, you can do something like...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions {  
    if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
        [FBSession sessionOpen];

        FBCacheDescriptor *cacheDescriptor = [FBFriendPickerViewController cacheDescriptor];
        [cacheDescriptor prefetchAndCacheForSession:FBSession.activeSession];
    }
   return YES;
}
```

There is a good example on Scrumptious demo app provided by Facebook.

You can execute FQL using the new API, but like I said tying that with the Cache is not documented anywhere. Here's how you can run FQL using the new SDK...

```
- (void)getFacebookFriends {
    NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    @"Your FQL Query goes here", @"query",
                                    nil];

    FBRequestConnection *connection = [FBRequestConnection new];

    FBRequestHandler handler =
    ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {        
        ........
        //Process the result or the error
        NSLog(@"%@", result);
    };

    FBRequest *request = [[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:FBSession.activeSession 
                                                 restMethod:@"fql.query" 
                                                 parameters:[params mutableCopy] 
                                                 HTTPMethod:HTTP_GET];

    [connection addRequest:request completionHandler:handler];

    [self.requestConnection cancel];    
    self.requestConnection = connection;  

    [connection start];  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Chateaudlfless. But still I don't know if it is possible to bind an FQL response to FBFriendPickerViewController.

Comment: I don't believe you can. You will need to use requestForGraphPath API and process the result set by yourself if you go down the FQL route, which may turn out to be slow. May I know why you want to use FQL instead?

Comment: List of all friends that share more than 10 mutual friends:
SELECT ... AND mutual_friend_count > 10 ORDER BY last_name